# Run only 10k requests per day and next day another 10k and so on

Tags: python, api

I'm just doing some program which fetches some data from some api.
I use yql to access yahoo geo stuff to match to some geonames id. For example:

```
def get_woeid(geonames_id):
  y = yql.Public()
  query = 'select * from geo.concordance where \
          namespace="geonames" and text="' + geonames_id + '"'
  result = y.execute(query)
  for row in result.rows:
      print row.get('woeid')
```

This function takes the geonames_id from the db and do a request to match that id to the woeid(where on earth id) from yahoo geo.

The problem is that this api thing just allows 10k requests per day, so I have to use some logic which gets 10k requests and "waits" and next day it will continue with the next 10k..
I could start a loop over all the data and if 10k requests are made, then do some wait or sleep stuff till next day, and do the rest, but this should be done better I think, but I don't really know how.

Hope someone could help out here.

Thank you :)

Comment: this sounds like a job for cron!

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Are you creating your own local database? That is probably against their terms of use for the API.

Comment: are you sure about doing this? can you try to fetch data on demand? did you try an open source db for geo? like geonames? just an idea! or you can pay yahoo for using more than 10k. I worked in a similar project using apis with limit (google in my case) and we never fetched more than 10k per day! (on demand and then cache the result for a time )

Comment: Andbdrew: I thought of this too, but how can I track which IDs I already updated, so to say which I had updated the last day(s)?
Neal: Yes, I create a db for myself where I have, for example all cities in Europe and its corresponding geonamesid and the woeid from yahoo. Do you think thats really against their terms of use?
llazzaro: On demand isn't really what I want to do. I want to have this data all accessible directly, because maybe in "production" there is the case that with many requests on "my service" the limit will be exceeded and than no more ID could be fetched..

Comment: @christian1337 Section 2 of their terms of use say you can't store results for more than 24 hours. They spent a lot of money to collect or buy this data, why would they let someone else create a copy of it for free and potentially profit? http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/api/api-2140.html. This is typical of pretty much anyone providing API access to their own databases. They want to remain the owner of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm gonna make it like this. I will save the id after each query and write a script that filters for objects with missing woeids and queries them (but not more than 10k) and runt the script daily with e.g. kronos.

Thanks to all :)